# Quartz Composer - Capture output of composition as input to another patch

Tags: quartz-composer

I'm looking to see if there is a way to capture the entire output of a quartz composer scene, or it could even be a scene within a macro patch, and use it as the input to another patch that accepts an image. My use case is an image filter that overlays something dynamically generated based on the input image.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you can do it but not in QuartzComposer.app**

To capture a `video`/`audio`/`images` from some QC patches you should use [AVCaptureSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturesession) and [AVCapturePhotoOutput](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotooutput) classes from `AVFoundation` framework in Xcode. Then you can easily pass this data to another QC patches. Of course, you need to have a good knowledge of Swift or Obj-C.